# Where was Joseph Brown Lever for 1841 England Census?

Tags: england, census-records, 1840s, staffordshire, northamptonshire

In a [self-deleted answer](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/7981) to [Tracing Hitchcox migration Liverpool-Adelaide in 1854 on ships Constance and Antelope?](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/questions/5508/tracing-hitchcox-migration-liverpool-adelaide-in-1854-on-ships-constance-and-o) user @GinnyButler mentioned that:

> On the 1841 census we find Joseph Brown Lever is working for Joseph
>   Ansell in his shop. His mother Letitia Lever is staying there too.
>   Presumably as a visitor.

Joseph Brown Lever later married my 2nd great grand aunt Alithea Hitchcox but I have not been able to locate him in the 1841 (or 1861) England Census.  Perhaps Joseph Ansell is her uncle Joseph Anslow or her great uncle of the same name.  Searching for Letitia Lever and Joseph Ansell has not helped me find the 1841 record either.

The information above suggests that the 1841 record has been found and it is one that I would like to review because I am curious about how Alithea from Wheaton Aston near Lapley, Staffordshire came to marry Joseph Lever Brown from Raunds, Northamptonshire.

Where was Joseph Brown Lever for the 1841 England Census?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This webpage claims he was in Wednesbury in 1841C: http://www.myheritage.com/person-1000489_150692981_150692981/joseph-brown-lever. Suggest you get creative with some wildcard searches....

Comment: That's the hint that I needed.  His name was recorded as Josh Lever.  I've now found him via FindMyPast and Ancestry.com in Class: HO107; Piece: 984; Book: 4; Civil Parish: Wednesbury; County: Staffordshire; Enumeration District: 12; Folio: 8; Page: 8; Line: 21; GSU roll: 474618 - and he appears to be living and working as a Shopman with Alithea's uncle Joseph Anslow (a Grocer).

Answer (score 2):

Based on the [hint by @user3310902](https://genealogy.stackexchange.com/a/7987/19) I used FindMyPast and Ancestry.com to (re-)locate Joseph Brown Lever in Wednesbury, Staffordshire, England:

> Class: HO107; Piece: 984; Book: 4; Civil Parish: Wednesbury; County:
>   Staffordshire; Enumeration District: 12; Folio: 8; Page: 8; Line: 21;
>   GSU roll: 474618

[image]

My interpretation of this household is:

- Jos[ep]h Anslow, 25, Grocer, born Staffordshire - this seems to be Alithea's maternal uncle who later became a Tea Merchant in St Helier, Jersey, Channel Islands
- Hannah Anslow, 25, not born in Staffordshire - I think she was Hannah Hodgetts who must have died before about 1855 when Joseph and daughter Sarah Hodgetts Anslow, 22, are in St Helier, Jersey, Channel Islands with a new wife and more children.  I have not yet identified birth, marriage or death records for Hannah with any certainty because the names Hannah Hodgetts and Hannah Anslow are not as uncommon as I would have thought.
- Sarah Anslow, 3, born Staffordshire
- Letitia Lever, 65, Independent, not born in Staffordshire - presumably mother of Jos[ep]h Lever below
- Jos[ep]h Lever, 25, Shopman, not born in Staffordshire - later marries Alithea Hitchcox
- 3 other Shopmen with whom I currently make no connection